# How to find which coordinate is touched in touch screen using libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, game-development

When we touch screen to give an input, how can we  find which point or the coordinate the user has touched?

I am talking about a touch screen.

And please answer this with respect to `libgdx gaming platform`.

Answer (score 2):

Its the same by using a mouse as is with a touch screen.

```
if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
    int x=Gdx.input.getX();
    int y=Gdx.input.getY();
    ...
}
```

Comment: will it returns in terms of pixels or inches

Comment: @suvimsgowda ,pixels ofcourse, with x=0 at the left edge and y=0 at the top edge.